# List with not computed numbers in Do loop

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

If I have a a `Do` loop such as:

```
Do[
list=AppendTo[tts, otherlist]
]//Print,{j,1,10,1}
```

which generates a list of 10 numbers for each iteration such as in first iteration `list={1}`, in the second `list={1,2}`, in the third  `list={1,2,3}` and so on (all are made up numbers) up to 10 different numbers. My question is: How can I create the list such as if I were to start the `j` at 3 such as `{j,3,10,1}` the number computed will go to the position designated by `j` (in this case 3) in the list rather than the first position while leaving the other two positions as `Not computed` such as `List={Not computed,Not computed,3}`. The same for any number of j up to 10.

EDIT: The code generated by @Bill is closed with what I want used as:

```
otherlist = 3;
Do[
 tts = Table["Not computed", {j - 1}];
 list = AppendTo[tts, otherlist] // Print,
 {j, 4, 10, 1}
]
```

The problem is that I am only interested in the first part of that output `{Not computed, Not computed, Not computed,3}` and not the rest.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `tts=Table["Not computed",{2}];Do[list=AppendTo[tts, otherlist]//Print,{j,3,10,1}];`

Comment: Maybe you know this already, but the combination of `Do` and `AppendTo` is notoriously a bad paradigm to generate lists in Mathematica...

Comment: @Bill what you posted is very close to what I want but not quite. I want something like this using your code: 
`otherlist = 3;
Do[
 tts = Table["Not computed", {j - 1}];
 list = AppendTo[tts, otherlist]
   // Print, {j, 4, 10, 1}]`
The problem with this part as it is is that the output is repeated many times I am only interested in the first part of the output of that code such as `{Not computed,Not computed,Not computed,3}`. I hope it helps clarify what I want and let me know if you have any question

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I did not know that! Could you tell me why and what would be a better option than `AppendTo` in order to store what is generated inside a loop?. I thought that was a "Classical way" to use anything that is generated inside a loop, outside of it.

Comment: The reason is that Mathematica cannot predict what you are going to add to the list next; a datum of the same type as the ones already there (ints, doubles, chars) or something completely different like a Word document, PDF, or an image. Hence, it must reallocate on each append, forcing a copy of the existing list. This scales horribly because each time you append, a longer and longer list must be copied.

Comment: Instead, use `Table` or `Array` to generate lists of known length, and if you can't predict the number of elements beforehand, use `Reap` and `Sow`.

Comment: "If I have a a Do loop ... which generates a list of 10 numbers" Did you actually try to run this code? It's completely wrong to the point that it won't even evaluate. I suggest you go step by step. Make sure that the code you use as illustration actually work. Then we can go from there and change it.

Comment: @Szabolcs no. The code it's just an illustration. But if you go to the edit you can see a code that works and what I want!. Thanks

Comment: If you could add to the end of your post a description of exactly what absolutely must be done and exactly how it must be done and everything else is don't-care no matter what it is or how it is done, maybe even include one line at a time showing the value of each variable for each iteration and the end of that line showing what is printed (or "" if nothing is printed) if that is what matters to you, then people could try to find six different ways of having it do what you showed. Trying to understand what is absolutely essential to you and what is free to change can be difficult to communicat

Answer (score 1):

This produces the same output as your second `Do` loop, but I am not sure that I understand what the code should really do:

```
Table[ConstantArray["Not computed", j - 1]~Join~{otherlist}, {j, 4, 10}]

(* Out: 
{{"Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", 3}, 
 {"Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", 3}, 
 {"Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", 3}, 
 {"Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", 3},
 {"Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", 3},
 {"Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", 3},
 {"Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", "Not computed", 3}}
*)
```